# irssi: no terminal notification sound while pinged

Tags: 13.10, sound, irssi

### Initial Problem:

Installed a fresh copy of irssi for my terminal. All settings are default. My goal is when someone pings my username, I am alerted through a sound notification.

### Initial Settings:

I went to terminal's profile preferences and checked:

`terminal bell = true`

I also tried a few settings within irssi:

```
/set beep_when_window_active ON"
/set beep_when_away ON"
/set beep_msg_level MSGS NOTICES DCC DCCMSGS HILIGHT"
/set bell_beeps ON"
```

After all settings, sound notification does not occur upon ping. What other settings am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

By default, irssi looks to the computer speaker to produce sound. By default, `pcspkr` is not loaded in many linux distros --including, Ubuntu 13.10.

### Initial Solution:

```
cd $HOME/.irssi/scripts # make a scripts directory if one does not already exist
wget http://scripts.irssi.org/scripts/beep_beep.pl
cp $HOME/Music/custom_beep_example.wav . # wget or cp a custom notification sound
mkdir $HOME/.irssi/scripts/autorun
cd $HOME/.irssi/scripts/autorun
ln -s ../beep_beep.pl #create symbolic link for auto-run
```

After running through these commands, launch up irssi in your terminal and run the following commands:

```
/set bell_beeps
/set beep_msg_level MSGS DCC DCCMSGS HILIGHT NOTICES
/set beep_cmd aplay -q ~/.irssi/scripts/custom_beep_example.wav
/save
```

That's it! You should be ready to rock-in-roll!

### Options:

You can append your `beep_message_level` with `ALL` for all Levels:

`/set beep_msg_level MSGS DCC DCCMSGS HILIGHT NOTICES ALL`

Another option is to change the `beep_flood` in the perl script to `300000 (5 minutes)`. If you get a message on IRC within the flood time, it will *not* beep, otherwise, it will.

Credits go to [andrew.46](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=208550) and [suicidefunky](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=1329444) from [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) for finding the initial and optional solution.

Comment: Good to see that little bit of work is still useful :). I still use this on my own system....

Comment: @andrew.46 You might want to upvote this answer as well?

Comment: @Anwar Looks like I did quite some time ago :)

Comment: @andrew.46 but the only vote I see is mine :)

Comment: @Anwar I see 2 up and 1 down?

Comment: @andrew sorry for bothering you. I should have checked the counts.

Comment: @Anwar No problems! This solution (that I helped create!) I have been using on irssi ever since this time :)

Comment: Note from the future: [`bell_beeps` was removed entirely](https://github.com/irssi/irssi/issues/524) because it is considered useless (it allows people in the channel to make your terminal beep by sending ^G in chat, which is rarely what you want).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the beep level to CTCP or ALL if you like:
`/set beep_msg_level CTCP`
The ping requests are CTCP level.