# (Xubuntu) how to get Terminal to beep so my IRSSI will beep on every private msg?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, notification, irssi

How to enable Terminal sound beep? I tried some of this [Beep in shell script not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working?newreg=24ce26f5fae4428bb7e3d78de2cf053b)
without luck.

Please help me, I just want IRSSI to make a beep sound each time I get a private message.

Comment: can your box make speaker-sounds? (not all boxes do).  I'd just suggest using `paplay` [pulse-audio play] or other and use an appropriate sound file, eg. worf from star trek with his "you're being hailed" :)

Comment: can u explain how i do that

Comment: in a script I have a line `paplay --volume=85000 /usr/share/sounds/KDE-Sys-App-Error-Serious-Very.ogg` which plays a selected file if that error condition occurs.  the sound file of course can be anything (I too use XFCE on the box I grabbed this example from but I did use KDE4 years ago)

Comment: FILE OR FOLDER NOT FOUND remember im on xfce not KDE

Comment: I assume you copy/pasted my command into your shell. doing this assumes you have the file I used (I used KDE4 years ago I said which is why I likely found it on my my xfce box; pick one you have already in that directory).  you'll have to change the file to one you have (plenty are available online; where I found the startrek one I mentioned earlier as a droll.joke), eg. `paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg` is one you're more likely to have.

Comment: paplay --volume=85000 /usr/share/sounds/message.oga worked but printf '\a' and irssi sounds doesent work

Comment: sorry I was distracted by the 'beep in bash script' & lost the irssi purpose. I don't know irssi but a quick [early] scan revealed scripts so I hoped `paplay` would help. alas a better look just now and scripts appear to only run at startup so of little help.

Comment: Answer might be here: https://askubuntu.com/q/470944/57576